# RabbitMQ - view what is holding memory open

Tags: rabbitmq

Does anyone know of a way to determine what objects are in memory for rabbitmq?

This is on the server side.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Can you make this question a little more specific.  Are you talking about server side or client side memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Running "rabbitmqct status" should do the trick for you.

[Check out the rabbitmq page to see what each of the sections mean](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory-use.html)